# Windows Phone lockscreen icon

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, lockscreen

I have a Windows Phone 8.0 witch can update the lock screen with count number and news updates. I have created a 38x38 icon with just white as color, but whatever I do it does not show up on the lock screen. The updates appear but the icon is displayed as an x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must manually edit WMAppManifest.xml and here is a property that specifies the path to your icon.

Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207048%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Working demo project: http://1drv.ms/1yxF7Qu

Comment: I have already followed that guide. i have           <DeviceLockImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">
            Assets\RTVLockIcon.png
          </DeviceLockImageURI> in my app manifest and the icon still displays as an x

Comment: Is your Build Action set to Content? Also check Copy to property of your icon.

Comment: RTVLockIcon.png has Build Action set to Content and Copy to Output Directory set to Do not copy

Comment: Try setting Copy to Output Directory to value If newer or Always

Comment: Thanks for the comment so far, I've tried with Always and if newer and the result is the same: an x instead of the icon

Comment: That is strange, isn't your icon somewhat unusual? I remember AppBar not displaying some of my icons because they had large white area. Could you try different icon to rule out this possibility?

Comment: http://i1375.photobucket.com/albums/ag472/Sergiu_Alexandrescu/RTV_LockIcon_zps4d915782.png this is the lock screen icon

Comment: i have inverted it. at first the text was white and the rest transparent, and it still displayed an x

Comment: Can you as a last idea try to create icon that has only something small in the middle?

Comment: I have just tried what you said: a 38x38 png with just a white box in the middle and the phone still shows an x on the lockscreen. Please help. I don't know what i am doing wrong

Comment: Created working project with simple icon, check it out. I have no idea why yours does not work...

Comment: thx, i will test soon with a fresh new project. Until then, could you please send me the icon that worked for you

Comment: You can find it in project Assets folder, named LockImage.png :)

Comment: i have just created a blank silverlight app, an there is no LockImage.png in Assets. Please send a link to an image

Comment: I meant Assets folder in my demo project.

Comment: IT WORKED!!! the problem was that i had  < DeviceLockImageURI IsRelative =" true" IsResource =" false" >
Assets\RTV_LockIcon.png
</ DeviceLockImageURI>
instead of <DeviceLockImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\RTV_LockIcon.png</DeviceLockImageURI> the difference is the newline before and after the file name